# Error reading MySQL incremental logs using Debezium

Tags: mysql, debezium

Error reading MySQL incremental logs using Debezium：

Failed to read remaining 1641 of 1665 bytes from position 21676915.Block length:17935.Initial block length:18094.

java.io.EOFException: Failed to read next byte from position 78.

why? what should i do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.